# Need help - Monogame 2d water reflection

Tags: xna, monogame, hlsl

Ok so i am following this tutorial [Water Reflection XNA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LlBfDM8btv4) and when i adjust code with monogame i cant get final result. 
So here is my LoadContent code:

```
protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("test");
        effect = Content.Load<Effect>("LinearFade");
        effect.Parameters["Visibility"].SetValue(0.7f);
    }
```

and my Draw code:

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
        //effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Vector2(texturePos.X, texturePos.Y + texture.Height), null, Color.White * 0.5f, 0f, Vector2.Zero, 1, SpriteEffects.FlipVertically, 0f);
        spriteBatch.End();

        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, texturePos, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();


        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

and finally my .fx file: **[LinearFade](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c7icqzfdir8rri2/LinearFade.fx?dl=0)**

So the problem starts when i apply effect. My texture just disappear and if i comment effect part in Draw method i get mirror image with fade (messing with alpha "Color.White * 0.5f") but without fade effect like he have on tutorial from middle of picture to the bottom of picture. I still dont have much experience in monogame and shader but i am learning.

If any1 know how to fix this or how to make it like on tutorial above it would be nice. Btw sry for bad english not my main language.

Answer (score 0):

Ok no need for help i got it after 2 day of thinking i know the answer. The thing is that you need default vertex shader input and output and then shader is working. So if any1 have problem with shaders in monogame first see if you have default vertex input and output. Will put solution code so if some1 doing same tutorial or similer thing so they know what is the problem.

Solution: [Working Effect.fx](https://www.dropbox.com/s/354c1q99c5daz5n/Effect.fx?dl=0)